# Java while loop Quiz doesn't reset

Tags: java, string, while-loop

As part of my course work, I've been tasked with creating a simple quiz game that loops until the user selects the correct answer.
I can generate the message prompt and response prompt when the answer is correct (the answer is B) or incorrect but I am struggling to get the while loop to reset and prompt the user again. 
Currently it infinite loops on the response prompt when the user gets the answer incorrect.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Quiz {      

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String question =  "What colour is the sky?\n";
     question += "A. Purple\n";
     question += "B. Blue\n";
     question += "C. Green\n";
     question += "D. Yellow\n";
     question += "E. Orange\n";

     String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
     answer = answer.toUpperCase();

     int guess = 0;
     while (answer != "B")

     if (answer.equals("B")) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct!");
         break;
        }
     else if (answer.equals("A")) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect. Please try again!");
        }
     else if (answer.equals("C")) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect. Please try again!");
        }
     else if (answer.equals("D")) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect. Please try again!");
        }
     else if (answer.equals("E")) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect. Please try again!");
        }
     else {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid answer. Please enter A, B, C, D, or E.");
        }
     guess++;
}
}
```

Comment: `guess++;` is not part of the `while` loop, FYI.

Comment: Also `while (answer != "B")` and `if (answer.equals("B"))` these statements are contradictory.

Comment: Use brackets (`{ ...}`) for your loop

Comment: Inside your while loop you never change the value of the variable `answer`. So the loop will either run not at all or infinite times.

Comment: If you check equality with `equals`, why do you check inequality with `!=`? and have a look at [switch case](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: Also if you correct the brackets you are not doing anything with the `guess`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to give an opportunity to answer the question again.
Now it's working how you intended.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String question =  "What is the Capital of South Africa?\n";
    question += "A. Cape town\n";
    question += "B. Pretoria\n";
    question += "C. Johannesburg\n";
    question += "D. Durban\n";
    question += "E. Nelspruit\n";

    String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
    answer = answer.toUpperCase();

    int guess = 0;
    while (answer != "B") {
        answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
        answer = answer.toUpperCase();
        if (answer.equals("B")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct!");
            break;
        } else if (answer.equals("A")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect. Please try again!");
        } else if (answer.equals("C")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect. Please try again!");
        } else if (answer.equals("D")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect. Please try again!");
        } else if (answer.equals("E")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect. Please try again!");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid answer. Please enter A, B, C, D, or E.");
        }
        guess++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some suggestion put the `answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
        answer = answer.toUpperCase();` at the end of the while loop also `while (answer != "B")` should be `while("B".equals(answer))`

Answer (score 0):

instead of..

```
while (answer != "B"){

         answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
         answer = answer.toUpperCase();

         if (answer.equals("B")) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct!");
             break;
            }
         else if (answer.equals("A")) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect. Please try again!");
            }
         else if (answer.equals("C")) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect. Please try again!");
            }
         else if (answer.equals("D")) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect. Please try again!");
            }
         else if (answer.equals("E")) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect. Please try again!");
            }
         else {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid answer. Please enter A, B, C, D, or E.");
            }
         guess++;
}
```

you missed brace.

Comment: Instead of what? Also, if you mean the braces, that's not the only problem.

Comment: `while (answer != "B")` should be `while("B".equals(answer))`

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam oh i missed that you are right! String values must use equals function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prompt question again and again if the user input is not `B`. And inside while loop you need to change the value of the variable `answer`. Try below working snippet.

```
public class Quiz{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String answer = promptQuestion();

        while (answer != "B") {
            if (answer.equals("B")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct!");
                break;
            } else if (answer.equals("A")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect. Please try again!");
                answer = promptQuestion();
            } else if (answer.equals("C")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect. Please try again!");
                answer = promptQuestion();
            } else if (answer.equals("D")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect. Please try again!");
                answer = promptQuestion();
            } else if (answer.equals("E")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect. Please try again!");
                answer = promptQuestion();
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid answer. Please enter A, B, C, D, or E.");
                answer = promptQuestion();
            }
        }
    }

    public static String promptQuestion() {
        String question = "What is the Capital of South Africa?\n";
        question += "A. Cape town\n";
        question += "B. Pretoria\n";
        question += "C. Johannesburg\n";
        question += "D. Durban\n";
        question += "E. Nelspruit\n";

        String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
        return answer.toUpperCase();
    }

}
```